# AS3 Microphone levels decrease over time - built-in noise compensation?

Tags: flash, audio, air, microphone, noise-reduction

I am trying to measure microphone levels using ActionScript 3 and Adobe AIR. The process should be quite simple, but the results I'm getting are bizarre. While executing the code, if I create a steady stream of noise (for example, blowing in the microphone or recording a crowd), after a few seconds, the levels reported from the Microphone drop off completely. If I stop the noise floor and then restart, the microphone levels spike up again.

It looks like there's some additional processing being done on the mic input, but I don't know how to turn it off. I have tried:

```
setSilenceLevel(0)
setUseEchoSuppression(false)
```

and even

```
codec = SoundCodec.SPEEK
enableVAR = false;
noiseSuppressionLevel = 0;
```

This phenomenon seems to occur both with the basic `microphone.activityLevel` as well as a more comprehensive analysis of the sample data ByteArray.

Take a look at this example: http://www.audiostretch.com/spectrum/ which is not my code, but illustrates the phenomenon. Try blowing into your mic while maintaining a steady volume for about 2 seconds. Suddenly the spectrum just drops off. Stop blowing and start up again and it's back!

**Update**
I even tried changing the `silenceLevel` periodically, as per below. This appeared to address the problem in initial tests, but subsequent testing has shown that this is not the case.

```
var resetTimer = new Timer(2500);
resetTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, resetMicrophone);
resetTimer.start();

// later...
private function resetMicrophone(event:TimerEvent):void {
    trace("Microphone OFF");
    microphone.setSilenceLevel(100);

    setTimeout(function() {
        microphone.setSilenceLevel(0);
        trace("Microphone ON");
    }, 250);
}
```

So, anyone tackle this issue and have a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must be a platform-specific issue.  I just tested in Safari with the latest (debugger) Flash player version (14,0,0,145), using a Logitech C170 webcam for the mic; with a steady sound source, there was no drop in levels in the spectrum analyzer, even after a minute.  I suggest checking you go to your Systems Preferences (on Mac) or Control Panel (Windows), and in the audio settings look for "Automatic Gain Control" (AGC), "Background Noise Suppression", or anything vaguely like that, and turn it off.

Comment: Hey thanks for swinging by to answer Gerry. I think you're right. I'm running the same code across desktop and on iOS and on iOS, not seeing any of the dropout I describe, whereas on Mac / Win AIR I'm seeing it. It must be hardware / OS related.